# How Load a Huge/heavy scene smoothly in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a very very **Big/Huge scene** to load and I can't load it at once.

What I have tried so far is **I divided the scene into multiple scenes and loading it into async manner as my *character controller move*.** I am moving my character controller and accordingly loading (its near)scenes by matching its position. **But it is not smooth. . .**

How do I load big scene smoothly? what will be the strategy? Is this right strategy which I am doing or there is any other feasible and easy to use solution available.?

Answer (score 0):

Try separate your scene into small chunks. When you move your character - just load new chunks and unload old. For example, this strategy uses minecraft.

You can't decrease loading time to zero milliseconds, but loading will be smooth. You can use chunks about 5x5x5 meters. And load from manager with coroutines.

Don't forget to use [object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern#C.23) (because Instantiate it very costly) :)

**UPD:**

For example, this way use in plugins:

[Uniblocks Voxel Terrain](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14768)

[MapMagic World Generator](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56762)

Also, this plugins uses open world generation from 2d/3d noises (Perlin noise, etc.)

Comment: if i use small chunks then, it take time to load what to do

Comment: Mohammad Faizan Khan, yes, but for load small chunk you waste few milliseconds - in optimized case it will give "smooth loading" effect for user.